# Xpath syntax to retrieve a specific list

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm learning the basics of XPath and I can't seem to take this list properly in my Google Sheet document:

[The List](https://www.agronomiforestali-rer.it/ordine-di-ravenna/albo-iscritti/)

To import the data in my Google Sheet, I'm using the function:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.agronomiforestali-rer.it/ordine-di-ravenna/albo-iscritti";"//td")
```

With this I can successfully import the whole page, but it's too much data. All I care is the list above.

Is there a way to understand what's the correct query_xpath?

Comment: Is it MS Excel or Google Sheet?

Comment: it's google sheet

Comment: edit 06/19/18 added google sheet instead of excel

Comment: IMPORTXML doesn't support XPath. as per doc. Did you check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) of google sheet says,

> query - Either **"list"** or **"table"** depending on what type of structure contains the desired data.

For your case it should be `table`. And I can see its 3rd table in the uri. Hence following should work

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.agronomiforestali-rer.it/ordine-di-ravenna/albo-%20iscritti/", "table", 3)
```

Comment: I didn't see xpath is supported